# GitHub Action CI - Download and set JDK

Tags: maven, github, github-actions

I am faced with following situation.

I have a maven project and want to use the maven GitHub Action Workflow to integrate CI for the project.

I need to set a specific JDK version - which is not available in the setup-java action. -
Therefore I need to download the specific version and then set it within my workflow.

What would be the appropriate solution for this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use SDKMAN on Linux and macOS agents.
For example, to download the latest Java 8-zulu:

```
# Install SDKMAN:
- curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
- Source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"

# Install Java 8:
- sdk install java `sdk list java | grep -E "8.[0-9]*.[0-9]*-zulu" | head -1 | awk '{print $NF}'`

# Set JAVA_HOME:
- export JAVA_HOME=$HOME/.sdkman/candidates/java/current

# Print Java version
- java -version
```

You can change "8.*-zulu" to what ever you want. To see all available Java versions that SDKMAN supports just install SDKMAN on a local Linux/macOS machine and run `sdk list java`.